# ошибка при установке Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

Поставил Drupal вот такой командой `composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:~8.0 . --stability dev --no-interaction` и после установки(без ошибок) выдает вот такой лог ошибок по адресу `http://www.drupal.test/core/install.php` (drupal.test это мой виртуальный хост)

```
    Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.
Original

TypeError: Return value of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::reset() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\void, none returned in Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::reset() (line 55 of /var/www/drupal.test/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php).

Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::reset() (Line: 113)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Plugin\Discovery\AnnotatedClassDiscovery->getDefinitions() (Line: 86)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDefinitions() (Line: 283)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->findDefinitions() (Line: 174)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions() (Line: 109)
Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager->buildInfo('seven') (Line: 76)
Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager->getInfo('form') (Line: 806)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->prepareForm('install_select_language_form', Array, Object) (Line: 272)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm('install_select_language_form', Object) (Line: 890)
install_get_form('Drupal\Core\Installer\Form\SelectLanguageForm', Array) (Line: 1316)
install_select_language(Array) (Line: 662)
install_run_task(Array, Array) (Line: 540)
install_run_tasks(Array) (Line: 117)
install_drupal(Object) (Line: 44)

Additional

TypeError: Return value of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::reset() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\void, none returned in Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::reset() (line 55 of /var/www/drupal.test/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php).

Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::reset() (Line: 113)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Plugin\Discovery\AnnotatedClassDiscovery->getDefinitions() (Line: 86)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDefinitions() (Line: 283)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->findDefinitions() (Line: 174)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions() (Line: 109)
Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager->buildInfo('seven') (Line: 76)
Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager->getInfo('html') (Line: 298)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, 1) (Line: 195)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, 1) (Line: 139)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->Drupal\Core\Render\{closure}() (Line: 576)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 140)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->renderRoot(Array) (Line: 66)
Drupal\Core\Render\BareHtmlPageRenderer->renderBarePage(Array, 'Error', 'install_page', Array) (Line: 76)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Render\BareHtmlPageRenderer->renderBarePage(Array, 'Error', 'install_page', Array) (Line: 996)
install_display_output(Array, Array, Array) (Line: 264)
_drupal_log_error(Array, 1) (Line: 584)
_drupal_exception_handler(Object)
```

Comment: удалить и скачать архив установить через обычный установщик ...

Comment: Но всё же интересно что не так именно с стандартной установкой

Comment: И к тому же твой способ не помог

Comment: мне приходилось это делать много раз ... у меня это работало всегда

Comment: Смотри, я скачиваю архив tar.gz распаковываю, даю все права и у меня получается что без установки опять же просто формы входа на HTML без всяких стилей и перед этим к тому же я не вводил ничего вроде имени пользователя, или пароля

Comment: ты пользуешься Линуксом ?

Comment: Да, Ubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что Doctrine обновился, и у него в требованиях php7.1, а на сервере другая.

Решения 2:

1. [тут](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/upgrading-drupal/2017-10-06/update-to-84-with-composer#comment-12297309), это можно проверить командой `composer show -t >
   dependencies.txt`
2. в composer.json [ограничить версию php](https://www.drupal.org/node/2913970#comment-12292929).

Comment: да, у меня 7.0 но в файле описано что это допустимая версия https://hastebin.com/aduqurokof.lua

Comment: Возможно в этой ветке будет найден ответ: https://www.drupal.org/node/2913970